# Transfer array of objects to array of only one attribute in ruby

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I am trying to Transfer **array of objects** to **array of only one attribute** in ruby.
example -
I have something like this :

```
arr = [       
 {
   name: hihihihi,
   phone: null,
   email: test@test.com,
   position: null
 },
 {
   name: hi,
   phone: null,
   email: test2@test.com,
   position: null
 }
]
```

and i want the output to be:

```
["test@test.com","test2@test.com"]
```

(to make an array (with apostrophe) just form the email attribute)

Thank you

I would like to find out the most efficient way to do so

Comment: This is what [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) is for – it maps each element to the result of the given block.

Comment: ...namely, `arr.map { |h| ??? }`, where the block variable `h` holds each element of `arr`. I've named it "h" because the elements of `arr` are hashes. When `h` equals the first element of `arr` (`h = { name: hihihihi, phone: null, email: test@test.com, position: null}`) you need to convert (i.e., `map`) that to the value of `:email` in `h`, namely, `h[:email]`. Similar for all remaining elements of `arr`, of which there is one. Note that Ruby has no object `null`. Perhaps you mean `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very straightforward with `#map` once we correct your syntax in defining `arr` a bit.

```
arr = [       
 {
   name: 'hihihihi',
   phone: 'null',
   email: 'test@test.com',
   position: 'null'
 },
 {
   name: 'hi',
   phone: 'null',
   email: 'test2@test.com',
   position: 'null'
 }
]

arr.map { |h| h[:email] }
```